# Can OCIExtractToInt be used to get parameters from query?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I wonder if the C-Functions `OCIExtractToInt` and other `OCIExtractToXXX` provided by [OCI](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci20ext004.htm#i446828) could be used to extract data from statements? And if so how this could work? Sadly I could not find any example where something like this is done. Additionally the Oracle documentation does not help much at this point.

Comment: What data are you trying to extract from statements?

Comment: Data coming from select statements (e.g. `select id from table where cond>100;`). I know about `OCIDefineByPos`, but I just wanted to know if that could also done with `OCIExtractToInt`